# DB2 Connect vs ODBC/JDBC driver

Tags: database, jdbc, db2, odbc

What exactly **IBM DB2 Connect**, which is available in 2 different editions - [**Enterprise**](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/db2connect-ee), and **Personal** - does? My understanding from the product descriptions so far is that it enables client applications connect to IBM's DB2 UDB on mainframe and minicomputers (z/OS, and AS400 and its successors, such as iSeries, System i etc). So, **DB2 Connect** is functionally similar to an  ODBC, or JDBC driver, but with some features? What are some those features that make **DB2 Connect** a separate product?

Comment: I think this question is off-topic, but maybe this helps: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0503katsnelson/

Answer (score 4):

DB2 Connect is what you call a *gateway* -- it translates the protocol used by the ODBC/CLI driver into the DRDA protocol used by DB2 on z/OS and System i. In other words, you need both the ODBC driver and the DB2 Connect instance to talk to a DB2 database on the mainframe.

The DB2 JDBC driver, on the other hand, speaks DRDA so the gateway is not necessary; JDBC programs can access DB2 on the mainframe and System i directly (although they need an appropriate license to do that).